# DataTable with DateTime Column throws "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time"

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, ado.net, table-valued-parameters

I am trying to call a stored procedure that accepts a Table Value Parameter with one string and one date time column.

Stored Proc

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspStoredProcedureDateTimeTableValueTest]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Param DateTimeType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


END
```

TVP:

```
CREATE TYPE DateTimeType AS TABLE 
(
    Name nvarchar(50),
    ModifiedDate datetime
)
```

.NET Console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            DataTable table = new DataTable("Test");
            table.Columns.Add("ModifiedDate", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = "David";
            row["ModifiedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
            table.Rows.Add(row);

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("uspStoredProcedureDateTimeTableValueTest", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", table);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Whenever I try to execute this SP from .NET I am getting an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting date and/or
>   time from character string.
>
> The data for table-valued parameter "@Param" doesn't conform to the
>   table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is: 241, state: 1
>
> The statement has been terminated.

It seems to work when I only have the DateTime parameter. But adding the additional 'Name' parameter has apparently caused some problems.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you have to create a SqlParameter with type = SqlDbType.Structured and pass that to your stored procedure

Answer (score 7):

When using ADO.Net to send table valued parameters, the order of the columns of the data table must match exactly the order of the columns of the user defined table type. I don't know if that's a bug or a feature, but that's just how it works.

You need to switch the order of the next two rows in your c# code:

```
table.Columns.Add("ModifiedDate", typeof(DateTime));
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
```

Also, [Do not use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Instead, use `Add`:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Param", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one key thing. The parameter you add to the command must be of `SqlDbType.Structured`.

```
var param = new SqlParameter(); 
param.ParameterName= "@Param"; 
param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured; 
param.Value = table; 
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```